# python getting the dicts of a list with a particular key/value pair when key:None exists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, filtering

I would like to extract the `dict`s of a list of `dict`s as follows:

```
mylist= [{'a':1,'b':3},{'a':71,'d':33},{'e':51,'b':63},{'e':51,'b':63}]
```

under the condition that a dictionary contains a particular key/pair value.
Observe that the dictionaries are not all of the same length, i.e. of the same keys

If that would the case this would work:

```
#given
condition = {'a':1}

key = next(iter(condition.keys())).lower()
value = next(iter(condition.values())).lower()
filtered = [doc for doc in self.data if value.lower() in doc.get(key, "justastring").lower()]
```

So far so good.

Now imagine that the `list` of `dict`s is a API response that might look like this:

```
mylist= [{'a':None,'b':3},{'a':71,'d':33},{'e':None,'b':63},{'e':51,'b':63}]
```

The above code gives the error:

```
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

So `{'a': None}` should behave as if a would not exist.

Some ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you can just use a list comprehension with a condition that all the keys in condition are in the dict and the value is the same. That might look like:

```
mylist= [{'a':None,'b':3},{'a':1,'d':33},{'e':None,'b':63},{'a':51,'b':63}]
condition = {'a':1}

[d for d in mylist if all(k in d and d[k] == v for k, v in condition.items())]
# [{'a': 1, 'd': 33}]
```

This will allow a condition with more than one key and should handle conditions like `condition = {'a':None}` without issue (it would produce `[{'a':None,'b':3}]` with the above input).

Answer (score 1):

You can add an extra condition in the `list` comprehension to skip over any `None` values.

```
filtered = [
    doc for doc in self.data
    # First check for None then check for membership in doc
    if doc.get(key) is not None and value.lower() in doc.get(key, "justastring").lower()
]
```

`if` will evaluate lazily i.e. it will evaluate to `False` if the first predicate is `False` without even checking the second predicate in an `and` expression. Equally, a boolean `or` expression will evaluate to `True` if the first predicate evaluates to `True`.

For example

```
In [16]: a = 1

# a == 2 evaluates to False, no need to evaluate the second predicate
In [17]: a == 2 and a.lower() == 1
Out[17]: False

# Similarly a == 1 evaluates to True, no need to evaluate the second predicate
In [18]: a == 1 or a.lower() == 1
Out[18]: True
```

This way your code will never try to evaluate `var in None`.

If you want to be even safer you could do the following to guard against non-`str` values of `value`. But this might not conform to your API spec.

```
filtered = [
    doc for doc in self.data
    # First check for string then check for membership in doc
    if isinstance(doc.get(key), str) and value.lower() in doc.get(key, "justastring").lower()
]
```